# Oracle update: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle

```
UPDATE TMP_COLUMNS 
    SET COLUMNNAME = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM 
                      user_tab_columns usertable
                      WHERE
                      table_name = table_Name
                      AND usertable.column_id = TMP_COLUMNS.idcolumn)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                  FROM 
                  user_tab_columns usertable
                  WHERE
                  table_name = table_Name
                  AND usertable.column_id = TMP_COLUMNS.idcolumn);

    COMMIT;
```

I am getting the error `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, this is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mnagel points out, the error is occurring because your subquery (`SET COLUMNNAME = SELECT ...`) is returning more than one row.

The problem is probably here:

```
WHERE table_name = table_Name
```

You need to do something like this instead:

```
WHERE table_name = tmp_columns.something
```

Or if there isn't a table name column in `tmp_columns`, you need to supply the table name as a constant:

```
WHERE table_name = 'something'
```

Answer (score 4):

you do:

```
UPDATE TMP_COLUMNS SET COLUMNNAME = ( *SOMETHING* );
```

where SOMETHING is

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns usertable WHERE table_name = table_Name AND usertable.column_id = TMP_COLUMNS.idcolumn
```

that something returns more than one row, so your update is broken as it needs to know the new value to update to (and that needs to be exactly one value and not multiple rows).

run the something part alone and fix it to return the proper value.

also: dont write such long lines ;)

Comment: To add (and confirm), from [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01427_single_row_subquery_returns_more_than_one_row.htm):

    The Oracle docs note this on the ora-01427 error*:

    'ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row'
     
    **Cause:** The outer query must use one of the keywords ANY, ALL, IN, or NOT IN to specify values to compare because the subquery returned more than one row.
     
    **Action:** Use ANY, ALL, IN, or NOT IN to specify which values to compare or reword the query so only one row is retrieved.

Comment: Ok, I added this but still it fails                            SELECT distinct usertable.COLUMN_NAME FROM 
                      user_tab_columns usertable,TMP_COLUMNS
                      WHERE
                      table_name = 'tableName'
                      AND usertable.column_id = TMP_COLUMNS.idcolumn